# 2D Rotation Issue C++ DirectX

Tags: c++, math, drawing, directx

So I'm trying to rotate a point about another point in a window, drawing it with DirectX. My issue is that the rotation is in a weird shape:

http://prntscr.com/iynh5f

What I'm doing is just rotating a point around the center of a window and drawing lines between the points.

```
vec2_t vecCenter1 { gui.iWindowSize[ 0 ] / 2.f, gui.iWindowSize[ 1 ] / 2.f };
for ( float i { 0.f }; i < 360.f; i += 2.f )
{
    vec2_t vecLocation { vecCenter1.x, vecCenter1.y - 100.f };
    static vec2_t vecOldLocation = vecLocation;
    vecLocation.Rotate( i, vecCenter1 );
    if ( i > 0.f )
        Line( vecOldLocation, vecLocation, 2, true, D3DCOLOR_ARGB( 255, 255, 255, 255 ) );
    vecOldLocation = vecLocation;
}
```

Here is my rotation:

```
void vec2_t::Rotate( float flDegrees, vec2_t vecSubtractVector ) 
{
    flDegrees = ToRadian( flDegrees );

    float flSin = sin( flDegrees );
    float flCos = cos( flDegrees );

    *this -= vecSubtractVector;

    x = x * flCos - y * flSin;
    y = x * flSin + y * flCos;

    *this += vecSubtractVector;
}
```

I've tried a few different methods of rotation and none of them seem to work. If anyone could tell my what I'm doing wrong, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key lines:

```
x = x * flCos - y * flSin;
y = x * flSin + y * flCos;  << problem
```

The second line is using the *modified* value of `x`, whereas it should be using the original. You must cache both coordinates (or at least `x`) before updating:

```
void vec2_t::Rotate( float flDegrees, vec2_t vecSubtractVector ) 
{
    float flRadians = ToRadian( flDegrees );

    float flSin = sin( flRadians );
    float flCos = cos( flRadians );

    // cache both values + pre-subtract
    float xOld = x - vecSubtractVector.x;
    float yOld = y - vecSubtractVector.y;

    // perform the rotation and add back
    x = xOld * flCos - yOld * flSin + vecSubtractVector.x;
    y = xOld * flSin + yOld * flCos + vecSubtractVector.y;
}
```

---

- To get rid of the if-statement in your for-loop, just compute the first point outside the loop, and start from the delta value instead of zero
- Don't use `static` because it might cause thread safety issues (although not important in your case) - just declare it outside the loop
- You seem to be missing a line segment - the condition needs to be `<= 360.f` (ideally plus an epsilon)

  ```
  vec2_t vecCenter1 = { gui.iWindowSize[ 0 ] / 2.f, gui.iWindowSize[ 1 ] / 2.f };

  const float delta_angle = 2.f;
  vec2_t vecOldLocation = { vecCenter1.x, vecCenter1.y - 100.f };
  for ( float i = delta_angle; i <= 360.f; i += delta_angle ) // complete cycle
  {
      vec2_t vecLocation = { vecCenter1.x, vecCenter1.y - 100.f };
      vecLocation.Rotate( i, vecCenter1 );
      Line( vecOldLocation, vecLocation, 2, true,   // no if statement
            D3DCOLOR_ARGB( 255, 255, 255, 255 ) );
      vecOldLocation = vecLocation;
  }
  ```